# Using MAX when selecting a high number of fields in a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I understand some varieties of this question have been asked, but I could not find an answer to my specific scenario.

My query has over 50 fields being selected, and only one of them is an aggregate, using MAX(). On the GROUP BY clause, I would only like to pass two specific fields, name and UserID, not all 50 to make the query run. See small subset below.

```
SELECT 
t1.name,
MAX(t2.id) as UserID,
t3.age,
t3.height,
t3.dob,
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
LEFT JOIN table3 t3 ON t1.id = t3.id 
GROUP BY t1.name, UserID
```

Is there any workaround or better approach to accomplish my goal?
The database is SQL Server and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you need to clearly communicate your desired result. Provide sample output to make it even clearer.

Comment: edited per your suggestion. thank you

Comment: I am still confused, especially since your SQL is invalid (GROUP BY t1.name, UserID). Please create an SQL Fiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: Pass all 50 attributes.

Comment: Hi Alex, I would like to group it just by name and id. sorry i used the alias, rather than the field. I understand this query doesn't run, as it raises the error i listed on my question. I know to fix i would need to pass all other non-aggregated fields in the group by clause, i was just checking if there could be a different way to only group by those two fields. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmmm . . .  What values do you want for the other fields?  If you want the `max()` of one column for each `id` and `code`, you can do:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, max(col) over (partition by id, code) as maxcol
      from t
     ) t
where col = maxcol;
```

Given that `id` might be unique, you might want the maximum `id` as well as the other columns for each `code`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, max(id) over (partition by code) as maxid
      from t
     ) t
where id = maxid;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I am still trying to use your solution on my case, where i need to group by name and id. I have not been able to yet, but I will let you know as if I am successful.